# Seguridad en FPDF

Tags: mysqli, fpdf

Buenas mi problema es que yo genero y guardo las facturas con formato `pdf` en una carpeta dentro del `www`, por lo tanto cualquiera puede entrar desde la `URL`.

Mi pregunta es si puedo agregar una medida de seguridad de usuario `php` para que solo un usuario pueda entrar en esas "paginas pdf", Desde ya muchas gracias.

Codigo de generar factura `pdf`:`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['nombreusuarioBD']) && $_SESSION['rolBD'] < 3){
    // libreria para generar pdf
    require_once ('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
        
    class PDF extends FPDF{
        function Header(){    
            //datos cabecera
        }        
            
        function Footer(){
            //datos footer
        }
    }
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf ->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    
    require '../conexion/conexionbd.php';
    // conseguimos la id de la factura recien creada
    $consulta = "SELECT  id_factura from facturas where id_factura = (select 
    max(id_factura) from facturas)";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    if ($fila){
        // generamos nuevo pdf y lo guardamos con el nombre de la factura en carpeta facturaspdf
         $nrofactura = $fila['id_factura'];
         $pdf->Output('facturaspdf/factura'.$nrofactura.'.pdf','f');
         $pdf->Output();
     }
`
```

Comment: "si puedo agregar una medida de seguridad de usuario php", si y deberias.. guardar algo que identifique al usuario y lo una al pdf, y solo lo dejes pasar si tiene acceso a ese pdf...

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he hecho de esta forma

1.- La carpeta de los PDF la dejas inaccesible desde la web, pero con permisos para que PHP pueda operar sobre ella

2.- Creas una pagina, digamos que `FacturasPDF.php`, ella será la encargada de validar la sesión de usuario, y de ser valido buscará el PDF y lo enviará como respuesta.

```
if(!isset($_GET["idFactura"])) echo "error"; //aquí ve tu que pones cuando no se recibe el parámetro adecuado

//compruebas la session
if(!isset($_SESSION['nombreusuarioBD']) echo "error session";

$idFactura = $_GET["idFactura"].".pdf";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$idFactura.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile('facturaspdf/factura'.$idFactura);
exit;
```

3.- Finalmente puedes llamar al PDF por la url `FacturasPDF.php?idFactura=12345`

Comment: Muchas gracias!